# how to append sheet before next function run

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm appending a row in a spreadsheet from a form then taking the data that was added to the spreadsheet and populating a document template. From there I'm creating a PDF and emailing it to myself.  The problem I'm facing is that the data is always coming from the second to last row of the spreadsheet instead of the newly appended row (from the latest form data). It seems like the appended data is not being saved before the AutoFillDocFromTemplate function runs. What am I missing?

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
};

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}

/* @Process Form */
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nz2uIWab1eSirljzvNn6SyNyxz3npDTu4mqVYV0blsU/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  ws.appendRow([formObject.company_name,
                formObject.identity_transformation,
  formObject.character_want,
  formObject.external_problem,
  formObject.internal_problem,
  formObject.philisophical_problem,
  formObject.empathy,
  formObject.authority,
  formObject.plan_step1,
  formObject.plan_step2,
  formObject.plan_step3,
  formObject.direct_cta,
  formObject.transitional_cta,
  formObject.failure,
  formObject.success]);
}
 

/* This function creates a new document from a template and updates the placeholder with info from a Google Sheet*/
function AutofillDocFromTemplate(){
 // Get the spreadsheet & sheet
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nz2uIWab1eSirljzvNn6SyNyxz3npDTu4mqVYV0blsU/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheetByName("Data");

  // Set the range to the last row of data in the Sheet
  var data = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),1,1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();  
  // Get the original template Doc
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1yu5jzg4NbRtTy_UjwzBmnpc-3_pNOqA-l1_UVsiAIWQ");
  // Get the folder for where the docs should go
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1prOQxp5jmDvJqiwIfLbbkLYWoz5QlTUC");
  // Create the new file name
  const newFileName = ("BrandScript")
  // Create a copy of the template doc
  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(newFileName, folder);
  // Open the new temp doc
  const openDoc = DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  // Get the body of the new temp doc
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  // Replace placeholders with spreadsheet data from last row
  body.replaceText("%company_name%", data[0][0]);
  body.replaceText("%identity_transformation%", data[0][1]);
  body.replaceText("%character_want%", data[0][2]);
  body.replaceText("%external_problem%", data[0][3]);
  body.replaceText("%internal_problem%", data[0][4]);
  body.replaceText("%philisophical_problem%", data[0][5]);
  body.replaceText("%empathy%", data[0][6]);
  body.replaceText("%authority%", data[0][7]);
  body.replaceText("%plan_step1%", data[0][8]);
  body.replaceText("%plan_step2%", data[0][9]);
  body.replaceText("%plan_step3%", data[0][10]);
  body.replaceText("%direct_cta%", data[0][11]);
  body.replaceText("%transitional_cta%", data[0][12]);
  body.replaceText("%failure%", data[0][13]);
  body.replaceText("%success%", data[0][14]);
 
  // Save and close the new doc
  openDoc.saveAndClose();
  //Send email with new document
  var message = "Attached is your draft BrandScript"; // Customize message
  var emailTo = "to be inserted" // replace with your email
  var subject = "Your Draft BrandScript"; // customize subject 
  var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(openDoc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'DraftBrandScript.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'}; // customize file name: "Autogenerated template"
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});
            
}
```

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);    
      
      
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    google.script.run.AutofillDocFromTemplate();
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    
  }
  
 
</script>
```

Comment: From your script, I cannot understand that how is `AutofillDocFromTemplate` called. Can I ask you about it? And although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, when `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` is put to the last line of the function `processForm`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. I tried the SpreadsheetApp.flush();  however it didn't make any noticeable differences.  Everything works the way I want from start to finish except the form data always pulls from the wrong row. It always pulls data from the second to last row.

Comment: Also @Tanaike... I'm using this javascript. Added it to my original post above.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. At first, I apologize that my 1st proposal was not useful for your situation. From your additional script, I proposed the modification points of 2 patterns as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If those were not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is `google.script.run` works with the  asynchronous process. By this, at the following script,

```
google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
google.script.run.AutofillDocFromTemplate();
```

Before `processForm` is not finished, `AutofillDocFromTemplate` is run. So in order to remove your issue, I would like to propose the following patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `withSuccessHandler` is used. By this, `AutofillDocFromTemplate` is run after `processForm` was run.

#### From:

```
google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
google.script.run.AutofillDocFromTemplate();
```

#### To:

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => google.script.run.AutofillDocFromTemplate()).processForm(formObject);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Google Apps Script is modified. By this, `AutofillDocFromTemplate` is run after `processForm` was run.

#### Google Apps Script side:

From:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nz2uIWab1eSirljzvNn6SyNyxz3npDTu4mqVYV0blsU/edit#gid=0";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  
  ws.appendRow([formObject.company_name,
                formObject.identity_transformation,
  formObject.character_want,
  formObject.external_problem,
  formObject.internal_problem,
  formObject.philisophical_problem,
  formObject.empathy,
  formObject.authority,
  formObject.plan_step1,
  formObject.plan_step2,
  formObject.plan_step3,
  formObject.direct_cta,
  formObject.transitional_cta,
  formObject.failure,
  formObject.success]);
  
  AutofillDocFromTemplate() //  <--- Added
}
```

#### HTML&Javascript side:

```
google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
// google.script.run.AutofillDocFromTemplate();  // <--- removed
```

### Note:

- If the issue was not resolved by above modifications, please try to use `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`.

### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)